# If $a$ is prime to $b$ and $y$, $b$ is prime to $x$ then prove that $ax+by$ is prime to $ab$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a$ is prime to $b$ and $y$, $b$ is prime to $x$ then prove that $ax+by$ is prime to $ab$.

I couldn't even think of a solution.

Please start by providing a hint and then a solution. I want to solve it myself.

Source-
Challenge and thrill of pre-college mathematics
Third edition 
Pg. 27 que. 18.

Answer (score 4):

Let $p$ be a prime which divides $ab$, $p$ divides $a$ or $b$.

If $p$ divides $a$ and $ax+by$ it idivides $by$ that is $b$ or $y$ impossible since $a$ is prime with $b$ and $y$.

If $p$ divides $b$, and $ax+by$ it divides $ax$ impossible since $b$ is prime with $a$ and $x$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Otherwise, there is a prime number $p$ which divides both $ax+by$ and $ab$. And, since $p\mid ab$ and $p$ is prime, $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if there is common nontrivial divisor of $ax+by$ and $ab$, then there is a prime divisor $p$.

If a prime $p$ divides a product $ab$, it divides a factor $a$ or $b$.

If $p$ divides $a$, then $p$ cannot divide $by$, since $a$ is prime to $b,y$ by hypothesis.
Thus $p$ does not divide $ax+by$.

If $p$ divides $b$, then $p$ cannot divide $ax$, since $b$ is prime to $a,x$ by hypothesis.
Thus $p$ does not divide $ax+by$.

It follows that $ax+by$ and $ab$ are coprime.